# How to make an an item in a Listbox visibile but unclickable

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have Listbox which is bound to my view model. This view model has a property

I need the item to be visible but unclickable with the change of this field. Any suggestion anyone

```
public interface IRegionAreaDM 
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the Focus Area
    /// </summary>
    string RegionAreaName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the Tab is currently selected.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the Tab is linked to any other Tab
    /// </summary>
    bool IsLinked { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

}

Each item is connected to an item in the XAML eg Name with a Textbox . IsSelected with a CheckBox and IsActive is to make the ListBoxItems Enabled/Disabled depending on the logic
and my Xaml style loooks something like this

```
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#00D05252"
                    BorderThickness="0,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
              <!--  <StackPanel x:Name="ParamterRoot" Orientation="Horizontal">  -->
              <Grid x:Name="ParamterRoot">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox x:Name="ParametersCheckbox" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" Margin="20,7.5,0,7.5"
                           Text="{Binding RegionAreaName}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                  <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                      <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                        </Trigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                  </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>                   
              </Grid>
              <!--  </StackPanel>  -->
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#FFC10000" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#FFC10000" />
              </Trigger>
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Do you want all items to be unclickable or just the ones that fit a certain criteria based on the vm property?  Please give some more details so that we can help you.

Comment: Just some items which will satisfy a certain criteria at a given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Code Behind: (you are using MVVM so you will adjust this code a little but to fit to your pattern)

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public Window1()
    {
        Items = new List<T>
                    {
                        new T{  Id = 1,Name = "qwe",IsEnabled = true},
                        new T{  Id = 2,Name = "asd",IsEnabled = false},
                        new T{  Id = 3,Name = "zxc",IsEnabled = true},
                        new T{  Id = 4,Name = "rty",IsEnabled = false},
                    };
        InitializeComponent();            
        DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class T
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Hope This Help

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna change something in your style trigger then you have to set this property in your style too! so just add the default IsEnabled setter to your style.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" /><!-- default -->
   ...from here your stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to setting IsEnabled woudld be to use the trigger to set the UIElement.IsHitTestVisible property.

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False"> 
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" /> 
 </DataTrigger>
```